# How to modify current ScreenManager to another

Tags: python-3.x, kivy, kivymd

Good afternoon.
I have a code structure with two ScreenManager:
id: sm ==> besides being my root it has only two screens

```
LoginScreen:
    name: 'screen_login'

MainScreen:
    name: 'main'
```

When the login is performed it directs me to the main screen:

On the screen named 'main' it has:

1 - MDToolbar
1 - MDNavigationLayout and it has a ScreenManager of
id: screen_manager with the following screens:

```
        ScreenRecycleView
        LoginScreen
        ScreenSingUp
        ScreenItem
```

1 - MDNavigationDrawer and it has a ContentNavigationDrawer with a creen_manager variable that inherits from the one described above.

There it is working beautifully!
I call any of the screens above and everything runs.

The problem is that I have a screen called

```
<ScreenRecycleView>:
    name: 'recycle_view'
```

and this one has a MyImageCard class that has a button:

MDFlatButton:
text: "New Screen Here"
increment_width: "164dp"

On it I click and I can't call the screen that I pointed out in the example.

```
    on_release:
        app.root.screen_manager.current = 'screen_item'
```

I've tried everything I know, I'm for your help.

Below is my code reduced to the max to help them help me:

[My code here.](https://gist.github.com/CoutinhoElias/25888ad9b1f24cc7353f31f420d13019)

I know my problem is screen manager but I can't solve it!

Answer (score 0):

**With your help I was able to discover:**
app.root.get_screen('main').ids.screen_manager.current = 'screen_item'